# This script wont work how it is supposed to. Any errors you can spot?

Tags: batch-file

I am just starting programming in batch and I was making a script that opens calculator a given number of times, but it only opens it once

```
@echo off
:end
SET /p x=Value?
echo will start on key press
pause
:start
start calc.exe 
SET /a x=%x%-1
IF /i %x% EQU 0 (
goto end
) ELSE (
goto start
```

Comment: @DylanBonfield I suggest to read the help of the commands you try to use in your code. `EQU` is for comparing two __integers__ on equality. Using the option `/i` for a case-insensitive __string__ comparison does not make sense on comparing two integers. Run in a command prompt window `if /?` for help on command __IF__. Run also `set /?` for help on command __SET__ explaining usage of option `/A` for evaluating an __arithmetic expression__ on which environment variables can be used with just their names which is even highly recommended. Run also `start /?` for help on command __START__.

Comment: @DylanBonfield It is possible to use the string `start` as label in a batch file. But there is also the command __START__. For that reason it would be better to avoid the string `start` as label and use for example `begin` which is not a command. Run in a command prompt window `help` for a list of [Windows commands](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) (Microsoft documentation). See also [SS64.com - A-Z index of the Windows CMD command line](https://ss64.com/nt/) which documents the Windows commands even better than the MS docs.

Answer (score 1):

calc.exe is an UWP app, while still starting/initializing it seems to inhibit other instances.

Insert a small delay to overcome this:

```
:: SO_53876800.cmd
@echo off
:end
set "x="
SET /p x=Value?
if not defined x goto :Eof
:start
start calc.exe
SET /a x-=1
IF %x% lss 1 goto :end
timeout /t 1
goto start
```